# How to use local jquery in Typo3 v10

Tags: jquery, typo3, typoscript

Hallo I have upgraded from Typo3 v9 to Typo3 v10. Now my jquery configuration in typoscript is not working anymore.

```
page {
  javascriptLibs {
    jQuery = 1
    jQuery.version = latest
    jQuery.source = local
    jQuery.noConflict = 0
  }
}
```

I read that this is deprecated and I should use one of these options instead:

- page.includeJSLibs
- page.includeJSFooterlibs
- includeJS
- includeJSFooter

I don't get it to work with a the local jquery files that are included in the installation of typo3 v10. Can anyone tell me how this is supposed to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you have noticed [`page.javascriptLibs` was deprecated with TYPO3v9](https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-core/main/en-us/Changelog/9.2/Deprecation-83806-DeprecatePagejavascriptLibsAndPagejavascriptLibsjQuery.html) and [dropped with TYPO3v10](https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-core/main/en-us/Changelog/10.0/Breaking-87193-DeprecatedFunctionalityRemoved.html).

For a smooth update you should check the last jQuery version which was bundled with TYPO3v9, then download that and add it to your page using one of the options you mentioned. (Alternatively integrate a CDN URL.)

Comment: that s not true.  

javascriptLibs {
      jQuery = 1
      jQuery.version = latest
      jQuery.source = local
   }

worked until typo3 v9

see: https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-core/main/en-us/Changelog/9.2/Deprecation-83806-DeprecatePagejavascriptLibsAndPagejavascriptLibsjQuery.html

Comment: Yes, I was just pointed to the changelog which confirms that `page.javascriptLibs` was a thing. I'll adjust my answer.